# Kepler.gl change text label position

Tags: javascript, css, kepler.gl

I am adding an icon layer to the keplergl map. Sometimes I have 2 or more icons overlapping.
the problem is that the text labels are overlapping too. How can I access the text labels and change its position accordingly?

I tried to change the offset of the textLabel in the layer config without success. Any advice?
Thank you